# Greek characters in ggplot2 work for png but not svg file format

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I make a ggplot2 plot with Greek characters in the axis label, it looks fine when I save as a png but not as svg. Any suggestions?

Example:

```
 mydata <- data.frame(A = rnorm(10), 
                      B = rnorm(10))

 ggplot(mydata, aes(x = A, y = B)) +
    geom_point(size = 2) +
    ylab(expression("Change in [drug] ("*mu*"g/mL)"))

 ggsave("myplot.png")
 ggsave("myplot.svg")
```

png version:[image]

svg version:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to save it in another way:

```
mydata <- data.frame(A = rnorm(10), 
                     B = rnorm(10))
svg("myplot.svg")
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = A, y = B)) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  ylab(expression("Change in [drug] ("*mu*"g/mL)"))
dev.off()
```

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thanks!